# The Itō integral $\sum_{i=1}^nH_{t_{i-1}}\left(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}}\right)$ of an simple process $H$ is independent of the choice of $(t_0,\ldots,t_n)$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $\mathbb F=(\mathcal F)_{t\ge 0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$
- $B=(B_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be an $\mathbb F$-adapted Brownian motion with respect to $\mathbb F$

Let $H=(H_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be $\mathbb F$-adapted, locally bounded and of the form $$H_t(\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^nH_{t_{i-1}}(\omega)1_{(t_{i-1},t_i]}(t)\;\;\;\text{for all }\Omega\times[0,\infty)\;$$ for some $0=t_0<\ldots<t_n$. The Itō integral of $H$ with respect to $B$ is defined as $$I_\infty^B(H):=\sum_{i=1}^nH_{t_{i-1}}\left(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}}\right)\;.\tag{1}$$

Let $\mathcal E$ be the set of all such $H$. Many people state, that $$I_\infty^B: \mathcal E\to\mathcal L^2(\operatorname P)$$ is a linear mapping. But, begin a mapping would mean, that if we choose another partition $(t_0',\ldots,t_{n'}')$ such that $$H_t(\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^{n'}H_{t'_{i-1}}(\omega)1_{(t'_{i-1},t'_i]}(t)\;\;\;\text{for all }\Omega\times[0,\infty)\;,$$ we would need to have $$\sum_{i=1}^nH_{t_{i-1}}\left(B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n'}H_{t'_{i-1}}\left(B_{t'_i}-B_{t'_{i-1}}\right)\;,$$ but I absolutely don't understand why this should be the case.

Comment: What is meant here is if you take another stochastic process $G$ with $G_t(\omega) = \sum_{j =1}^m G_{s_{j-1}}(\omega)1_{(s_{i-1},s_i]}(t)$ such that $G$ and $H$ in your question are *indistinguishable* then the integral of these $G$ and $H$ will be indistinguishable again.

Comment: @Calculon Can you provide a proof?

Comment: I think so but the proof I have in mind is rather long (not complicated though). I will try to post something when I have time.

Comment: Do you know a reference for a proof, which shows, that $(1)$ is well-defined?

Comment: I don't wanna go into semantics but (1) is the definition of an Ito integral for simple integrands (just like the definition of Lebesgue integral for simple functions). You just take it at face value. So it doesn't make sense to ask whether it is well-defined or not. But I know what you mean. We of course want the integral to be the same if we choose a different partition for the same integrand. For that you can refer to the set of lecture notes which I had sent you before (under one of your old questions).

Comment: @Calculon I've updated my question, since I'm unsure whether or not you (and other users) really understood what I'm concerned about. In many textbooks we can read, that $I_\infty^B$ (as defined now in the question) is a linear isometry. But I don't even understand, why $I_\infty^B$ is a mapping at all. It seems to me, that we can choose two different partitions for a $H\in\mathcal E$ and would end with different values of $I_\infty^B$, i.e. $I_\infty^B$ would not be a well-defined mapping.

Comment: Please take a look at Lemma 5.8 in http://www.math.wisc.edu/~seppalai/courses/735/notes.pdf

Comment: In the sense that for each $i$ there exists a $K_i$ such that $\lvert\xi_i\rvert \leq K_i$ almost surely.

Comment: @0xbadf00d How would you prove that the integral of a simple function with respect to a "deterministic" measure (e.g. the Lebesgue measure) does not depend on the partition? Exactly the same argumentation works for stochastic integrals.